# variable assignment from inside of a block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using Objective-C from Swift. I have practically no objective-c experience. I'm trying to access game center with Apple's examples and retrieve top-10 leaderboard scores to use in Swift. However I'm stuck with basics of objective-c assignment where passing the retrieved score data back to caller. Could someone post a code example for how to handle this?

```
- (NSArray*) retrieveTopTenScores
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    NSArray *temp = nil;
    if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
    {
        leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
        leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
        leaderboardRequest.identifier = @"Appid";
        leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,10);
        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                // Handle the error.
                NSLog(@"error in score retrieval");
            }
            if (scores != nil)
            {
               temp = scores; //results to Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)               
            }
        }];
    }
    return temp;

}
```

Comment: Declare it as `__block NSArray *temp = nil;` So the warning will go, but the return value will be a null, because your scores is being loaded on a asynchronous method, so the return statement will execute before you get the result

Comment: Best is to have your main application controller implement a method that handles the reception of the results e.g.

Comment: there is a fundamental problem with this design because by the time this completion handler is called temp has already been returned.  temp is only scoped locally, i.e. inside this method.   I think you should change this method signature to -(void). the array is not ready to return immediately. Then continue as you are, but set (this NSArray data) to an iVar or property, and then trigger another method to notify of the returned result..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your return value will be `nil`. This is because the `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` is an asynchronous method that executes in a background thread and can take time to download the data. The execution reaches the `return temp` before the block finished execution. In order to save the `scores` data, you can define a `property` in the class.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *topTenScores;
```

You can then assign the property inside the block. You can also update the UI by making a function call on the main thread from inside the block, if you want to display your toptenscore.

```
[leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) 
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
         // Handle the error.
         NSLog(@"error in score retrieval");
    }
    if (scores != nil)
    {
         self.topTenScores = score;
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           // Update the UI on the main thread.
         });
    }
 }];
```

Comment: Yep, I commented up pretty much the same thing just as you typed this.  +1

Comment: No, the `retrieveTopTenScores` has no business updating the user interface. Also the choice of whether to have a class property holding the top scores, or not, is a completely different issue. Sure, you might want to have a class property with the scores, but that has nothing to do with the asynchronous nature of this method.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling asynchronous method, so you should adopt asynchronous pattern. Nowadays the most common convention is to use blocks (just like the `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` method that Apple provided). Bottom line, rather than trying to return the `NSArray` immediately, provide your own `retrieveTopTenScores` method a block that will be called when the request is done:

The simplest rendition would be something like:

```
- (void)retrieveTopTenScoresWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *scores, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

    if (leaderboardRequest != nil) {
        leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
        leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
        leaderboardRequest.identifier = @"Appid";
        leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,10);
        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like:

```
[self retrieveTopTenScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    if (scores) {
        // use scores array here
    } else {
        //do something with error here

        NSLog(@"retrieveTopTenScoresWithCompletionHandler error: %@", error);
    }
}];

// but do not try to use `scores` here, because the above runs asynchronously
// and thus, we don't have the scores by the time we get here
```

Note, if you want that completion block to run on the main queue (which is critical if you're updating UI or model objects), then you might want to do something like the following (but just call it like you did above):

```
- (void)retrieveTopTenScoresWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *scores, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

    if (leaderboardRequest != nil) {
        leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
        leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
        leaderboardRequest.identifier = @"Appid";
        leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,10);
        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionHandler(scores, error);
            });
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is if you have your main application controller implement a method that handles the reception of the leaderboards, e.g:

```
- (void) handleResultsOfLeaderBoardRequest: (NSArray *) leaderboards error: (NSError *error) {
    // store the list in an attribute or process otherwise
}
```

Then you pass a call to this method as the callback handler to the intended leaderboards request.

Answer (score 0):

Using blocks is similar to coding in Javascript. The resulting data arrives later -- even after the method finishes executing. So you can't return the array.

Everything indented after loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: will happen /after/ the scores are loaded. You will need to update the UI inside that code block.